# javascript: IFrame-SRC as new Window?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a web application in which I have a bunch of iFrame from with source from other tools.
Now the user should have the possibility to open the iframe content in a new window / new tab, normaly I would simply add something like this:

```
function onButtonClick() { var src =    $('#iframe').prop('src');
windows.open(src, "_blank"); }
```

But his would only open a new version of my iFrame context, e.g. if a user open a page in the iframe or clicked on something and javascript changed something within my iframe, the user would be loosing this value..

So, can I make a iframe Content to a new window content without loosing the dynamic state of the website within my iframe?

Comment: If the iframe content is from a different domain, then you can not access the currently displayed URL, the Same Origin Policy prevents that.

Comment: Assuming Same Origin, you still won't be able to do this without *losing the dynamic state of the website*

Comment: Yeah I know that but in fact isn't a iFrame not simply the same as a window or a tab? - if yes, you can move a firefox windows to a firefox tab / drag&Drop between firefox processes as you want, why not doing the same with an iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot move around iframes between different windows without reloading, because the spec says the attributes must be reevaluated:

> When an iframe element is inserted into a document that has a browsing context, the user agent must create a nested browsing context, and then process the iframe attributes for the "first time".
>
> -- https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-iframe-element
>
> <sup>(via https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=254144#c97)</sup>

---

*Old answer:*

// edit: Does not work as expected, since the iframe is reloaded on move and the original src is restored.

<s>It is easy enough if you move the iframe out of the current page:</s>

```
<button id="example-button">open in new window</button>

<div id="example-container">
    <iframe id="example-iframe" src="https://example.com/">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

```
document.getElementById('example-button').addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    var win = open('about:blank');
    var iframe = document.getElementById('example-iframe');

    // the popup might not be immediately available:
    setTimeout(function () {
        var body = win.document.body;

        body.style.padding = 0;
        body.style.margin = 0;
        body.appendChild(iframe);

        iframe.style.position = 'fixed';
        iframe.style.padding = 0;
        iframe.style.margin = 0;
        iframe.style.width = '100%';
        iframe.style.height = '100%';
        iframe.style.border = 0;
    }, 0);

    // move the iframe back if the popup in closed
    win.addEventListener('beforeunload', function () {
        document.getElementById('example-container').appendChild(iframe);

        iframe.style.position = '';
        iframe.style.padding = '';
        iframe.style.margin = '';
        iframe.style.width = '';
        iframe.style.height = '';
        iframe.style.border = '';
    });
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cpy2jykv/1/

Comment: OK, I wasted my time trying, because it cannot be done, because the spec says it must not be done. :(